# array creates object with index name of variable

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an array with two arrays inside it but when I print it or convert it to json I get an object with the index name of the variable I used to create the sub-arrays.

```
    $var1 = [];
    $var2 = [];

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM table1')) {
        while($id = $stmt->fetch_object()) {
            $var1[] = $id;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        unset($id);
    }

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM table2')) {
        while($id = $stmt->fetch_object()) {
            $var2[] = $id;
        }
    }

    return array($var1, $var2);
```

When I print it `var_dump($result);`:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#14 (1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } } [1]=> array(0) { } }
```

Why is there an object with the index name id?

I just need a simple array containing 2 subarrays and print them inside two `select` elements:

```
    $.get('/get?op=4', function (data) {
        var content = data,
            sale    = content[0],
            rent    = content[1];
            alert(sale);
        $('select[name="lists-sale"]').html(sale);
        $('select[name="lists-rent"]').html(rent);
    });
```

I echo and encode in json what is returned from the function in the `/get?op=4` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling **$stmt->fetch_object()** and you get what you ask for - an object that represents a row of data returned from the database.

Replace

```
while($id = $stmt->fetch_object()) {
  $var1[] = $id;
}
```

with

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch_object()) {
  $var1[] = $row->id;
}
```

to get an array of IDs.

Comment: Oooh, you got there just before me :)

Comment: Hmm I didn't know that, so that's why I was getting an object and the number as string instead of as an integer... Thanks! (I'll accept in 3 min)

Answer (score 0):

`$stmt->fetch_object()` fetches an object containing your results.

The object represents the entire row you are selecting, not an individual column.

If you were selecting multiple columns, your object would contain multiple properties.

Comment: Since when was `mysqli` depreciated?

Comment: My bad, got muddle up with mysql_* functions

Comment: PDO is still better :)

Comment: `mysqli` is not depecreated but I'm thinking on making the switch once I have the time to learn about it.